# Theano -- Mean of squared gradients

Tags: neural-network, gradient, theano

In theano, given a batch cost `cost` with shape (batch_size,), it is easy to compute the gradient of the mean cost, as in `T.grad(T.mean(cost,axis=0),p)` with p being a parameter used in the computation of `cost`. This is done efficiently by backpropagating the gradient through the computational graph. What I would now like to do is to compute the mean of the squared gradients over the batch. This can be done using the following piece of code:

```
import theano.tensor as T

g_square = T.mean(theano.scan(lambda i:T.grad(cost[i],p)**2,sequences=T.arange(cost.shape[0]))[0],axis=0)
```

Where for convenience `p` is assumed to be a single theano tensor and not a list of tensors.
The computation could be performed efficiently by simply backpropagating the gradient until the last step, and squaring the components of the last operation (which should be a sum over the batch index). I might be wrong on this one, but the computation should be as easy, and nearly as fast as a simple backpropagation. However, theano seems unable to optimize the computation, and it keeps using a loop, making computations extremely slow.

Would anyone know of a solution to make the computation efficient, either by forcing optimizations, expressing the computation in a different way, or even going through the backpropagation process ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do we know `batch_size` in advance (before function calls)?

Comment: @dontloo Indeed `batch_size` is available before function calls.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `g_square` happens to have complexity O(batch_size**2) instead of O(batch_size) as expected. This lets it appear incredibly slow for larger batch sizes.

The reason is because in every iteration the forward and backward pass is computed over the whole batch, even though just `cost[i]` for one data point is needed. 
I assume the input to the `cost` computation graph, `x`, is a tensor with the first dimension of size `batch_size`. Theano has no means to automatically slice this tensor along this dimension. Therefore computation is always done over the whole batch.

Unfortunately I see no better solution than slicing your input and doing the loop outside Theano:

```
# x: input data batch
batch_size = x.shape[0]
g_square_fun = theano.function( [p], T.grad(cost[0],p)**2) 

g_square_value = 0
for i in batch_size:
    g_square_value += g_square_fun( x[i:i+1])
```

Perhaps when future versions of Theano come with better build in capabilities to compute Jacobians there will be more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper in the Theano docs I found a solution that would **work in the compute graph**. Key idea is that you clone the graph of your network inside the scan function, thereby explicitly slicing the input tensor. I tried the following code and empirically it shows O(batch_size) as expected:

```
 # x: input data batch
 # assuming cost = network(x,p)

 from theano.gof.graph import clone_get_equiv

 def g_square(cost,p):

    g = T.zeros_like(p)

    def scan_fn( i, g, cost, p):
        # clone the graph computing cost, but slice it's input 
        cloned = clone_get_equiv([],[cost], 
                                 copy_inputs_and_orphans=False,
                                 memo={x: x[i:i+1]})
        cost_slice = cloned[cost].reshape([])
        return  g+T.grad(cost_slice,p)**2 

    result,updates = theano.reduce( scan_fn,
                                    outputs_info=g,
                                    sequences=[T.arange(cost.size)],
                                    non_sequences=[cost.flatten(),p])

    return result
```

Comment: Please don't add another answer, you should edit your older answer and add you new findings. flagging for closing this one